# Dynamically add AjaxControlToolkit.MaskedEditExtender

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to build a form designer that allows the user to customise a form. I would to add a Masked Edit Validator to certain fields, for instance dates. I have tried adding this. The result I get is no input mask (I expect to see something like **/**/*_*_).
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

I have added a Reference in the project to AjaxControlToolkit.dll.

On the aspx page:

```
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.1213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" %>
```

and:

```
    <form id="formTestSurveyForm" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" ></asp:ScriptManager>
</div>
```

On the aspx.cs page:

```
    case "DAT":
                            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                            tb.ID = "tbDat" + intQuestionCount.ToString();
                            tb.CssClass = "PositionCol3 SVSTextBox1";
                            tb.Width = 250;
                            // check for date range restricdtions and display in tooltip
                            strTooltip = "";
                            if (question.DateMaxDaysInPast != 0)
                            {
                                DateTime dtPastDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-Convert.ToInt32(question.DateMaxDaysInPast));
                                strTooltip = "Date must be after " + dtPastDate.ToShortDateString();
                            }
                            if (question.DateMaxDaysInFuture != 0)
                            {
                                DateTime dtFutureDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(question.DateMaxDaysInFuture));
                                if (strTooltip == "")
                                {
                                    strTooltip = "Date must be before " + dtFutureDate.ToShortDateString();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    strTooltip += " and before " + dtFutureDate.ToShortDateString();
                                }
                            }
                            tb.ToolTip = strTooltip; ;
                            // if this is a completed form look for saved response
                            if (intCompletedSurveyAnswerId != 0)
                            {
                                tb.Text = strAnswerText;
                            }
                            questionsPanel.Controls.Add(tb);

                            // add to list of controls
                            m_orderOfControls[intNumOfControls] = "TB";
                            intNumOfControls += 1;
                            // add to saved textboxes
                            m_dynamicTextBoxes[intTextBoxCount] = tb;
                            intTextBoxCount += 1;

                            // try add masked edit extender
                            AjaxControlToolkit.MaskedEditExtender maskedEdit = new AjaxControlToolkit.MaskedEditExtender();
                            maskedEdit.ID = "mk_" + tb.ID;
                            maskedEdit.TargetControlID = tb.ID;
                            maskedEdit.Mask = "99/99/9999";
                            maskedEdit.MaskType = AjaxControlToolkit.MaskedEditType.Date;
                            //maskedEdit.InputDirection = AjaxControlToolkit.MaskedEditInputDirection.RightToLeft;
                            questionsPanel.Controls.Add(maskedEdit);

                            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `ToolkitScriptManager` with AjaxControlToolkit controls.

Comment: That seems to work. But after a couplo of postbacks, I get this error: Extender controls may not be registered after PreRender.

Comment: You can edit your question including that new problem.

Comment: I thin I will make it a new question.